# foreach loop is changing the original values

Tags: javascript

When I call a foreach loop my values of the array are changed immediatly. I don't want that the original values are changed.

Its a small link generator where 2 parts of the IP adress is changed. I tried to copy the array before accessing it but it still changing the original values

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Section for links that have to be generated
    const generator = [
        ["name1", "http://10.[IP1].[IP2].1", "description"],
        ["name2", "http://10.[IP1].[IP2].2", "description2"],

    ];
    // Initialisation for DataTable
    var t = $('#links_table').DataTable({
        "paging":   false,
    });


    $('#addRow').on( 'click', function () {
        // Log the Variable before doing somthing
        console.log("___________old_______________________");
        console.log(generator);
        console.log("____________________________________");

        //HTML input for 4 numbers
        var number = $('#number').val();

        if (number <= 1000) {

            alert ("Please type in a number!");
        }else{
            var ip1 = number.substring(0, 2);
            var ip2 = number.substring(2, 4);
            // HTML checkbox (if the new adress should be tested) 
            var check = $('#check').prop('checked');

            generator.forEach(function(e) {

                //Build correct adress
                e[1] = e[1].replace("[IP1]", ip1);
                e[1] = e[1].replace("[IP2]", ip2);

                if (check == true){
                    //Test the new adress
                    $.ajax({
                        url: e[1],
                        method: "HEAD",
                        dataType: 'jsonp',
                        async: false,
                        statusCode: {
                            404: function () {
                                console.log("cant find: "+e);
                            },
                            200: function() {
                                addToTable(e);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }else{
                    addToTable(e);
                }
            } );
        }
        console.log("___________new_________________________");
        console.log(generator);
        console.log("____________________________________");

    } );
});

function addToTable(e){
    t = $('#links_table').DataTable();
    t.row.add( [
        e[0],
        '<a href="'+e[1]+'" target="_blank">'+e[1]+'</a>',
        e[2],
    ] ).draw(false);
    t.order();

}

</script>
```

```
___________old_______________________
Kopie.html:124 Array(2)
0: (3) ["name1", "http://10.22.33.1", "description"]
1: (3) ["name2", "http://10.22.33.2", "description2"]
length: 2__proto__: Array(0)

___________new_________________________
Kopie.html:167 Array(2)
0: (3) ["name1", "http://10.22.33.1", "description"]
1: (3) ["name2", "http://10.22.33.2", "description2"]
length: 2__proto__: Array(0)
```

As you can see the array is changed even before i run the code the first time

I expect that the original values are still

["name1", "http://10.[IP1].[IP2].1", "description"]
and not

["name1", "http://10.XX.YY.1", "description"]

I hope you can help me and thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a deep copy of the array and make changes in that

```
const generator = [
        ["name1", "http://10.[IP1].[IP2].1", "description"],
        ["name2", "http://10.[IP1].[IP2].2", "description2"],

    ];

let newArray =  JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(generator )); // loop this newArray
```

Comment: Thank you this is working. But I don't understand why this is necessary. In other languages a foreach loop is not changing the values

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a deep copy of the array, e.x like this:

```
generator.map((entry) => entry.slice()).forEach(function(e) {
    ...
})
```

Note: it will work only if your array is **one-level** deep

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
generator.forEach(e => {
    var newE = [ ...e ];
    <your_function_code_here>
});
```

Make sure to use `newE` instead of `e` now.